# No connection with router after changing its IP to network prefix

Tags: networking, router, ip, subnet, lede

I changed IP of my router from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.0, which is my network prefix. What should I do to retrieve connection to my router?

**UPDATE**

I am on LEDE project and router TP-Link Archer C7. One thing I came up with was running some startup script via USB drive. Do you have any ideas for such implementation?

Comment: I'm surprised it allowed that, it's an invalid IP address.  Either it's still on the previous .1.1 address, or it's reset itself to the factory default (probably also .1.1).  If you can't contact it on either, I'd suggest a hardware reset.

Comment: @Ian I am on LEDE project, what allows a lot. Aren't there any hack like running startup script from USB setting it back?

Comment: Factory reset and connect with default IP per that configuration and then reconfigure, push the config backup file back to it, etc.

Comment: Do you know how to restore factory settings on this router under lede? For me even 30-30-30 method does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try configuring your computer with the IP address `192.168.1.2` with the subnet mask `255.255.0.0`.

With the subnet mask `255.255.0.0`, the IP address `192.168.1.0` is just another node on the network instead of being the network address.

Once you've fixed your problem, put your computer's subnet mask back to whatever it was before.

This is all you can do from the *client* side to make communication with the router possible.  If the router is unresponsive despite this approach, then your only option is the reset of last resort on the router.

Comment: This generates timeout after some time

Comment: I mean timeout after attempting to connect over both http and ssh.

Comment: And it is actually an improvement, because the previous error was immediate unreachable response. But still does not enable to fix my issue completely.

Comment: If you ping the router do you get a response? If after pinging it, is there an entry for it in your arp cache (indicating it's responding to arp requests)?

Comment: Yup, pings are getting back, but arp keeps silence on it.

Comment: What I've proposed in my answer is *all* you can do from the client side to make it possible to communicate with the router. If the router can't process the IP traffic despite receiving it, then it looks like your only option is to reset it.  I'll update my answer accordingly.