# TP-Link Archer C7 with LEDE - factory settings restore

Tags: networking, router, restore, openwrt, lede

I have an issue with TP-Link Archer C7. I installed LEDE firmware on it and experimented with this stuff. One thing I did absently was changing its IP to 192.168.1.0 (I suppose it was its network prefix). Then I lost contact with it. For now I have some feedback from Stack Exchange ([No connection with router after changing its IP to network prefix](https://superuser.com/questions/1241260/no-connection-with-router-after-changing-its-ip-to-network-prefix)) and it seems there is no way to retrieve connection to my router back and the only thing that left to me is to restore factory settings. I tried restoring factory settings, but I haven't manage yet. Do you know what should I do in my case?

Comment: Just boot in failsafe mode and fix your configuration.

Comment: @DanielB what is the right way to run failsafe mode on my router? I am trying many methods but none of them work.

Comment: [It’s all in the documentation.](https://lede-project.org/docs/user-guide/failsafe_and_factory_reset) Did you not read it?

Comment: Off course I did. I didn't try only serial connection yet. The other methods doesn't work.

Comment: Highly unlikely. Which image did you install on your router?

Comment: Specific for EU. This solution https://mikepalmer.net/tp-link-archer-c7-ac1750-v2-tftp-recovery/ worked for me.